# Chromecast Custom Receiver HLS with segmented WebVTTS

Tags: android, chromecast

I am having an issue with getting the HLSStreamingProtocol to see the text tracks in the m3u8. Here is how I am initializing the media player.

```
window.host = new cast.player.api.Host({
   'mediaElement':mediaElement, 'url':url
});

protocol = cast.player.api.CreateHlsStreamingProtocol(host);
window.player.load(protocol, initStart);
```

This is how our manifest is structured.
https://gist.github.com/darussian/cc3b796f143a7f5c8c45ce1d6956625d

please note that urls have been removed but I have verified that they all return 200 responses and have cors enabled on the CDN

I attempt to enable the captions using the onMetadataLoaded callback

```
mediaManager.onMetadataLoaded = function(event) {
  console.log("onMetadataLoaded");
  console.log("protocol", protocol);
  window.player.enableCaptions(true);
  var streamInfo = protocol.getStreamInfo(0);
  console.log("Stream Count", protocol.getStreamCount());
  console.log("Stream Info", streamInfo);
}
```

Protocol#getStreamCount only returns one stream, the A/V.

Comment: To debug the issue, could you provide at least the full playlist contents or better a link to a test stream?

Comment: @AliNaddaf Our streams have very short expiration times so it would be very difficult to provide you with a testable stream. Does the media player support having segmented webvtts in the manifest?

Comment: My recommendation would be to open a ticket on our SDK site and include logs from receiver and a test stream with a larger window for expiration so someone can try to take a look and reproduce and debug it. If you can't provide a stream publicly, mention that in the ticket and someone will give you instructions to provide that through a private channel.

Comment: will do. thanks @AliNaddaf

Comment: opened issue https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=1000